# Customizing a manifest for the allocate device plugin

Tags: kubernetes

It is necessary to process the manifest of the created pod or deployment and send the results to the device plugin during the call to the allocate method.

For example
Input:

```
spec:
   containers:
   - name: test-pod
     ............
     resources:
       requests:
         devices: 1
         deviceb: 3
       limits:
         devices: 1
         deviceb: 3
```

After that gonna perform calculations, for example in a scheduler plugin, the result would be like **"a1b3someinfo"**, and then send that string to the Allocate of a custom device plugin (for example, place it in the `DevicesIDs` field in the `ContainerAllocateRequest` structure, which is the content of the `AllocateRequest` structure received by the `Allocate` method).

In which component is it possible to accept and process an incoming manifest `*.yaml` file? How can the result of my processing be delivered to the `device plugin` node?

Initially, I expected to solve the problem using scheduler plugins, but when I looked at the scheduler repository, it turned out that there were no `*.yaml` files and the device manager was not imported

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler reads the pod specifications from the manifest file and then decides which node to place on the pod on. Customizing the behavior of the scheduler, including processing the manifest file, like you can use a KubeSchedulerConfiguration. This configuration allows you to define scheduling profiles, which can be used to customize the scheduler implementation.

The device plugin itself runs on the Kubernetes nodes and communicates with the kubelet, which is the primary "node agent" that runs on each node. The device plugin implements gRPC services like Allocate and ListAndWatch, which are called during container creation and monitor the state of the devices.